# Crash unity after start editor with new version of unity

Tags: unity3d-editor

**Crash unity after start editor with new version of unity.
What now pls? :-(**

Unity Editor version: 2022.3.0f1

```
Launching bug reporter
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application is sxhutting down...
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Unity.ILPP.Runner.PostProcessingAssemblyLoadContext[0]
ALC ILPP context 1 is unloading
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QObject(0x7fce39f6d370), parent's thread is QThread(0x7fce69f07ad0), current thread is Thread(0x7fce6aa875c0)
```

there was no problem in the older version. PLS help me.